# How to Edit Media in Smartedit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Media has many attributes like real filename, alt text. How can these be made editable? In the current set up we can only remove/add a media. I am using Hybris 6.6

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That type of information is usually edited via backoffice, rather than SmartEdit. In SmartEdit, you only choose photos.